# Ionic3 Generate APK Issue

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am trying to creating APK from **Ionic3** project but it gives me error as in screen shot. My **JAVA_HOME** variable is set to **jdk-9.0.1** and **Path** variable is also pointing to **jdk-9.0.1/bin** and not other version is there of java or environment variables which point older version.
I am referring [this documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/) for APK generation.

So how can I fix it and generate APK?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [Java SE Development Kit 8u152](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and updating environment variables fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
CordovaError: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

Downgrade your JDK version. It had worked for me.